# Linq: creating a list taking left and right child of every Node in a List

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List nodes where Node is

```
public class Node
{
 public Node Left
 public Node Right
}
```

I'd like to extract a list which looks like this:

```
{nodes[0].Left, nodes[0].Right, nodes[1].Left, nodes[1].Right, ...}
```

I am trying with Aggregate, Concat, Select and SelectMany

Comment: So, you don't want the values, you want to 'rewrite' the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with SelectMany

```
var result = list.SelectMany(x=>new List<Node>(){x.Left, x.Right}).ToList();
```

Comment: That's what I thought but from the result the OP wants, I'm not sure that's right. His result doesn't hold the values

Comment: Yes, I wanted this! Thanks a lot and sorry for my English.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to add it also here? http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/68/linq-queries/346/flattening-a-sequence-of-sequences-using-selectmany

I would upvote also there if you like to introduce a new entry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var qry =
    from node in nodes
    let nodeValues = new Node[] { node.Left, node.Right }
    from subnode in nodeValues
    select subnode;
```

This will eventually restult in a `SelecMany`, just in query syntax.